# General user security

Tags: security, authentication, passwords

I just want to know if having 2FA on your login can actually mean that you don't need to worry about it if someone steals your username and password?

I know there is a problem if someone steals your phone, and can access an authentication app like Google Authenticator or Microsoft Authenticator and just enter the app and read the generated codes. But what are the odds of anyone actually being able to get access to your phone and accessing that such an app?

I am using 2FA in most of the services I am using because I feel much safer that way. But is it worth implementing it in your own services if your encryption system is not so good? Will it be critical if someone manages to break into my service and read everyone's usernames and passwords in the hypothetical situation where everyone is using 2FA and unique passwords anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts:

- Security tends to be better when there are more "layers" of it. A combination of username and password is one such layer. 2FA is another. Adding 2FA will no doubt improve your security, but you should still strive to keep your username and passwords secret. **Consider what happens if someone steals your phone, but is unable to get hold of your password. Use both.**
- Related: Logging into a system is not the only threat; information about an account is too: What if a user does not wish it to be known that he has an account in your system? If someone can access your database of usernames and passwords and the data is published, the whole world will know who your users are; perhaps this is not critical in your case, but [it can be in certain other cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashley_Madison_data_breach), and it`s a good principle to adhere to in any case. So **strive to keep both usernames and passwords secret, if possible**.
- I realize you already know this, but your *hypothetical situation* is just that - hypothetical. You should never assume that all your user's passwords will be unique to your service. Some users will do stupid things. That may not be your fault, nor your responsibility, but it is still considered good practice to do what you can to help them stay safe.
- If you are aware that your encryption system is "*not so good*", then you should obviously try to improve it.
- 2FA may not always work, or may not be an option for everyone in all cases. If it is not critical to your service, you might consider making it possible to opt out of. For some customers, choosing to accept a little more risk may be worth it for a slight reduction in "hassle" when logging in. For others, this minor "hassle" may be an insignificant price for better security. In any case, you should **offer 2FA as a possible improvement in security, and not as an excuse for lax security in other areas**.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I mentioned that hypotethical situation just cause I want to know what in that situation, even tho I know my hypothetical situation will never come to reality. Covering unreal situation is not bad for general knowledge.

I am not professional security guy so I will for sure not be able to make the best security in the world (not even close), but I think what I have in mind for my project is pretty much ok.

Is there something similar to 2FA that is worth implementing? (I don't wanna use anything that is related to SMS and confirmation emails).

Comment: I think you're off to a very good start if you use Google Authenticator or something similar. Not sure what you mean when you say "*something similar to 2FA*". Perhaps a more broad overview of security in general? Examples can be to make sure you have good backup-routines, an appropriate amount of logging in case something goes wrong, etc.  Remember, security is not only about avoiding problems, but also about being able to discover and handle them when they do arise anyway... ;)

Comment: This project I am doing is really big and my private (so I have a lot of time on my hand). I am not that experienced with big systems that have potential to have massive amount of users. I can always do something about security in the start, but I am scared about what will happen if something fails big time when it will be in production. That is the main reason for this general conversation. To be able to look wider on posibilities to get a clue on what else I can do. Experience and knowledge needs to be gained from somewhere :)